# Can I create custom Woocommerce checkout with fixed layout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages, woocommerce-theming

I have created a custom plugin for woocommerce and the question is can I create a custom Woocommerce checkout page with a fixed layout? so that no other plugin and theme can change my layout. same for the other pages.

I am using the `woocommerce_locate_template` and `template_include` hooks to enable my custom template.

But still, some plugins and themes change my fixed layout. Is this good practice if I use the `!important` in the style code?

Comment: You may remove `apply_filters()` & `do_action()` functions in the overridden template file to prevent other plugin and themes from changing the template content. But eeh... It's not a best practice and many people may complain that your plugin isn't compatible with blabla plugin, and they're right, it would not!